# my JPanel refuses to be focused

Tags: java, swing, focus

jf is a JFrame I'm trying to move a pixel in every 200 milliseconds. I created this method so I ciould pause the software for 200 milliseconds before cntinuing. millis and millisn are static longs.

```
public static void waitsec() {

        millis =System.currentTimeMillis();
        millisn =System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (millisn<(millis+200)){
                millisn=System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
                }
```

the following part is the part where I'm trying to make my JPanel (jp) to move slowly 50 pixels when a button is being pressed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent h){
if (h.getSource() == button){
    for (int i = 0; i <50; ++i){
        waitsec();
        out.println ("" + i);//I'm checkinf if the waitsec() is working OK
        x +=1;
        jp.setLocation(x, 0);
        totalGUI.repaint();
        jp.setVisible(true);//setting visible so I could focus on it
        jp.requestFocusInWindow (); //suspicious part
        jp.requestFocus ();  
}}
}
```

The results of running this program are:
The numbers appear in the console one after another with 200 mmillis between them as expected.
The JPanel is not moving all the way once the numbers stop appearing (the program is done running). and if I try to minimize and maximize the window it doesn't show up till the program is done running as if the program has no focus at all...
why doesn't it focus although I had set it visible and focused it?

Comment: Just a side note, a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) appears to much more appropriate for what you are trying to do.

Comment: You haven't make everything clear. In which thread you are controlling the movement ? How your action listener is being used ? Your way of pausing the thread is abruptly wrong. Using a `while(true)` loop for running 200 ms. What do you rhink how much cycle it will do in this 200 ms!!

Comment: @Sage, Based on the fact that the OP is performing this action within the `actionPerformed` method is highly likely that it's being done within the EDT - it's still an assumption, but I believe we can rely on it to a high defgree...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, at first i thought so and rushed to write an answer. Then again when i looked at his way of stopping thread using while(true) loop i had to step back. :(

Comment: @Sage It's still good of you to ask, as there's nothing stopping the OP from calling `actionPerformed` manually from a different thread, but added with the description of the problem, it was becoming obvious what the OP had done (from my point of view, as you see this question A LOT) :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer, beat me. did you read my answer from some other posts ? don't know, but it seems you read probably today :))

Comment: @Sage I should basically copy this answer to a text file and paste back each time ;)

Comment: want to do it again? Let me show you: [Check this question, same paintComponent(g) and same EDT issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620749/java-2d-game-repaint-makes-window-grey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of things...

Firstly, you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from processing any new events, including repaint events.  This will make your application appear as it has hung, because essentially, it has.

Secondly, instead of rolling your `waitSec` method, you should be taking advantage of the available API functionality, for example, instead of trying to loop until a time period has passed, which while consume CPU cycles, you should use `Thread.sleep` instead.

Having said that though, you should NEVER sleep within the context of the EDT.

Instead, you should use something like a `javax.swing.Timer` which can be configured to raise an event on a regular bases.  The benefit of this is it raises the event within the context of the EDT, making it safe to update the UI from within (unlike making your own Thread for example)

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Thirdly, `JPanel` is not focusable by default, so calling `requestFocusInWindow` is not likely to have any effect

Fourthly, by default, Swing makes use of layout managers, so you may actually be struggling against this as well

Comment: my timer is working well for printing the numbers. why not for the jpanel? is it really a focus problem? can i solve it without using the timer?

Comment: Swing is a single threaded model, any thing that stops it from processing it's events (including it's paint events), will prevent it from updating the UI.  The `System.out` is an immediate result.  No, you can not solve it without using some kind of background timer and `javax.swing.Timer` is the safest and easiest choice, as you don't need to mess about resyncing the calls back to the context of the EDT

Comment: @עמוסרום, `can i solve it without using the timer?` Why would two people suggest a Timer if it was not a better approach? Both times a Timer was suggested it was upvoted as well.